# Is there any way to access and retrieve data from the web in the background while running a java project?

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve data from a website, however, i want this to run in the background.

I have already managed to use a chrome extension, but it always opens up a chrome tab and displays the underlying actions.

Is it possible to retrieve data from the web without having to see the open chrome browser?

This is what i have so far:

```java
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
String pageContent = page.asText();
System.out.println(pageContent);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You can spawn a thread and run it in the background.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); new Thread(){
        public void run(){
        HtmlPage page = 
        webClient.getPage("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
        String pageContent = page.asText();
        System.out.println(pageContent);`
        }
      }.start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to give this a try!